# R - Export large dataframe into CSV

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

Beginner here: I have a list (see screenshot) called `Coins_list` from which I want to export the second dataframe stored in it called `data` into a csv. When I use the code

```
write.csv(Coins_list$data, file = "Coins_list_full_data.csv")
```

I get a huge CSV with a bunch of numbers from the column named `price` which apparently containts more dataframes, if I read the output correctly or at least display the data in the price column? How can I export this dataframe into CSV correctly? See screenshot for more details.
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: I was able to get the first four rows into CSV by using `df2 <- Coins_list$data write.csv(df2[1:4,], file="BTC_row.csv")`, however it now looks like R puts the price of all four rows within a list c(  ) and repeats it in each row? Any idea how to change that?

[image]

Comment: Excel is not synonymous with CSV. Further, Excel is IMO terrible with CSVs. What does the file look like if you open it in say Notepad(++)?

Comment: Okay thank you. File looks the same in notepad than the screenshot above in excel. First row: ```"","price","name","symbol","id","logo"``` and second row: ```"1",c(20538.0358457935, 1147.76583679836, 0.999609101918529, 1.00085184249598),"Bitcoin","BTC","bitcoin","https://image.tokeninsight.com/content/imgUrl/opengraph.png?x-oss-process=image/resize,l_160"```

Answer (score 1):

(I would post this as a comment but I have too few reputation)

Hey, you could try for starters to flatten the json file by going further than response list$content but looking at what's into the content with another $.

Else you could try getting data$price and see what pops up from there.

something like this:

```
names = list(data$symbol)

df = data.frame(price = NA, symbol = NA)

for (i in length(data)) {
  
  
  x = data.frame(price = data$price[i], symbol = names[i])
  
  df = inner_join(df, data)
  
  
}
```

to get a dataframe with price and symbol. I don't know how the data is nested so I'm just guessing.

It would be helpful to know from where you got the data for reproducibility.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I can't flatten the json file any further, nothing else comes after $content. I tried your code but I get an error saying "Error in `[.data.frame`(data$price, i) : not defined columns chosen". I am getting my data from this api ```https://api.tokeninsight.com/api/v1/coins/list``` but unfortunately I can't share the API key.

Comment: I see. Maybe you could provide the .json file in a pastebin, even a small part of it. I'm pretty sure there are ways to flatten it on R, I'm just used to do it in Python.
Anyway, since that nested dataframe is a list, I don't see why you cannot access the price from there. Maybe use the list instead :)